# Why doesn't my regex work in hbase rowfilter with my scan?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hbase

I don't understand why my regex doesn't work when scanning hbase.  Everything looks good to  me but for some reason, it's returning all keys when it should just return the ones I'm requesting

```
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("raw_data"), Bytes.toBytes(fileType));
        scan.setCaching(limit); 
        scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
        scan.setTimeRange(start, end);

        FilterList filters = new FilterList();          
        Filter rowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator("100_.*_\\d{10}"));
        filters.addFilter(rowFilter);           
        scan.setFilter(filters);

        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan, MTTRMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
```

The rowkey is stored as a string in hbase.  The rowkey is in the format of hash_servername_timestamp, e.g.

```
0_myserver.mydomain.com_1234567890
```

The hash can be any number from 0-199.  In the above filter, I just want to get all elements with hash = 100 but for some reason, the scan job appears to return other rowkeys in addition to the ones with hash = 100.

I've tried this with jar versions 1.0.1 and 1.2.0-cdh5.7.2.  What am I doing wrong that's making the regex not work?

Comment: What are other keys? Try adding anchors, BTW: `"^100_.*_\\d{10}$"`